# Prevent Default Value on Update only?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a column

```
Alter Table MyTable
Add MyColumn BIT Default 0
```

This works fine when I am inserting values from C#. I have another stored procedure call in a separate part of the app that updates this column to 1.

However when the user goes to this screen again, makes changes and updates the same row, then this column will default back to 0. How can I prevent that from happening? I only need the default value set on new row insert and not on existing row updates.

Comment: What SQL are yo using?  MSSQL?

Comment: Are re-retrieving the record upon navigation? If you have a SP that updates the record in the database and sets the value of `MyColumn` to 1, the `DEFAULT` constraint shouldn't cause the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Im using SSMS 2016. The column isn't even explicitly set on insert in our legacy code. its a new column. So thats why the default value since the column is not null. In a new application we do have the column name and on insert we update it to true. The issue is on the legacy code when the user updates the row it defaults back to 0

Comment: This probably happens in the code. The default value of int is 0, therefore, I believe somewhere in your code when the object gets instantiated, it will just default to 0, and when you Save or SubmitChanges() it will probably save it with that.